# Does a final version of the IBM VGA XGA Technical Reference Manual exist?

Tags: ibm, vga

I'm doing some bare metal programming and I'm getting a lot of information from the [IBM VGA XGA Technical Reference Manual May92](https://archive.org/details/bitsavers_ibmpccardseferenceManualMay92_1756350) document. The only reference I can find about this document, is this draft version from May 92.

Does a final version of this document exist, perhaps with another title?

Comment: That's part of the PS/2 Reference Manuals. Right?

Comment: Not sure what kind of information you are looking for, but VGA (and I suppose XGA) "bare metal" stuff is also explained in plenty of other documents, in case you can't find a final version.

Comment: @Raffzahn I had a look and http://www.mcamafia.de/pdf/pdfref.htm suggests that it is part of the PS/2 Reference Manuals indeed. I guess a copy of the final version never made it to the internet.

Comment: @dirkt I'm not concerned about the content, pretty sure it won't be very different from the final version. I asked mostly out of curiosity :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given that by 1992, even IBM had realised that the PS/2 line was a failure, and had already released the last model in the series at that point (if you even count the model 25, which was an ISA machine rather than MCA, so was really a PS/2 in name only...), I doubt there was a final version if the document was still in draft half way through 92.

(Reference: see list of PS/2 models on [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IBM_Personal_System/2#Models))